# ASUS RT-AC66N and PoE

Tags: networking, router, power-over-ethernet

I have an ASUS RT-AC66N router, and I will like to power the router by using PoE.

The required power input for the router is 19V DC and 1.58A.

But I haven't been able to find a solution where I'm sure it will work.

Are there any who know of a solution?

- If possible I would like PoE to transfer with a Gbit.

Comment: That is not a PoE-compatible device.

Comment: Is there any other way to use the network cable to power it?

Comment: You need to get  PoE (probably PoE+ or UPoE, based on the radios) device to use as a WAP.